# TeX maker software display the latex help in html

Tags: texmaker

This question is about the TeX maker software; I do not know other site to ask this. My problem would be a very silly thing but I really appreciate your help.

When I tried to watch the documentation in TeX maker through the tag Help/LaTeX Reference or Help/User manual, the program shows me the html code in a Text editor. Like following: [image]

could you help me please to display this properly.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you set the text editor as the default software to open html files. You should change your settings or manually open the file with a proper program, like Firefox or Chrome.

Comment: I just did that you said  yesterday as temporary solution. Because when I choose to open the file with Mozilla Firefox it opens the browser and of course the output is ok now. But before this happened, the document would be displayed in a windows within TeX Maker.